# spring boot tempory h2 database table empty in junit4 test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, h2, springjunit4classrunner

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.5 and want to do some JUnit4 testing. I have an Eclipse project that contains the test. During initializiation a temporay H2 database is created. I have a schema.xml and data.xml. The initialization is fine, but later three of 5 tables are empty.

First I had the database created by Spring boot. No code from my side, just the XML in the resources folder. This runs without any problems. Then I found that in the test three of the five tables are empty. The schema still exists, but not data.

I then changed to manual creation of the H2 database/datasource bean and in the same method I checked if all records are present. This made no difference in the test results. I could only show that just after creation the database is populated as expected. It seems that during bean creation and JUnit test some routine is doing a delete on three specific tables.

```
package de.unit4.financials;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.test.jdbc.JdbcTestUtils;


@SpringBootApplication
public class JUnitConfig {

Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();


@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    if (dataSource == null) {
        dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).setName("FanUtilDB")
                .addScript("classpath:schema.sql").addScript("classpath:data.sql").build();
    }
    logger.info("Datasource "+dataSource);
    testDB(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
    return dataSource;
}

public void testDB(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    countTableRows("oas_company", jdbcTemplate);
    countTableRows("oas_agm", jdbcTemplate);
    countTableRows("oas_agmlist", jdbcTemplate);
    countTableRows("com_usr", jdbcTemplate);
    countTableRows("com_capab", jdbcTemplate);
}

private void countTableRows(String name, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        int anzahl = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, name);
        logger.info(name + " = " + anzahl);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
08:58:16.007 [main] INFO  Datasource org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy@60094a13 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig getDataSource 54 
08:58:16.197 [main] INFO  oas_company = 28 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.199 [main] INFO  oas_agm = 2 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.201 [main] INFO  oas_agmlist = 2 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.203 [main] INFO  com_usr = 52 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.205 [main] INFO  com_capab = 17 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74
```

Later the JUnit test is run and it gives me this result:

```
08:58:19.099 [main] INFO  Datasource org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy@60094a13 || de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactory getCurrentPeriod 63 
08:58:19.127 [main] INFO  oas_company = 0 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.128 [main] INFO  oas_agm = 0 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.128 [main] INFO  oas_agmlist = 0 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.129 [main] INFO  com_usr = 52 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.130 [main] INFO  com_capab = 17 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40
```

The DataSource object seems to be the same, but the record count is different. During the test, the first three are empty.

Here is the test:

```
package de.unit4.financials;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.jdbc.JdbcTestUtils;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = JUnitConfig.class)
public class FinancialsUtilApplicationTests {

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testDB() {
        countTableRows("oas_company");
        countTableRows("oas_agm");
        countTableRows("oas_agmlist");
        countTableRows("com_usr");
        countTableRows("com_capab");
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     */
    private void countTableRows(String name) {
        int anzahl = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, name);
        logger.info(name + " = " + anzahl);
    }
}
```

Here is the full console output:

```
08:58:12.555 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.j.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest].
08:58:12.581 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper from class [org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper]
08:58:12.607 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Found explicit ContextLoader class [org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader] for context configuration attributes [ContextConfigurationAttributes@32e6e9c3 declaringClass = 'de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest', classes = '{class de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig}', locations = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader']
08:58:12.618 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.627 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]: using defaults.
08:58:12.644 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
08:58:12.672 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
08:58:12.688 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@73ad2d6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@7085bdee, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@1ce92674, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@5700d6b1]
08:58:12.692 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.694 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.718 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.j.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactoryTest].
08:58:12.718 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper from class [org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper]
08:58:12.720 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Found explicit ContextLoader class [org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader] for context configuration attributes [ContextConfigurationAttributes@4566e5bd declaringClass = 'de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactoryTest', classes = '{class de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig}', locations = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader']
08:58:12.721 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactoryTest]
08:58:12.722 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactoryTest]: using defaults.
08:58:12.727 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
08:58:12.729 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
08:58:12.729 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2d928643, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@5025a98f, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@49993335, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@20322d26]
08:58:12.729 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactoryTest]
08:58:12.730 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactoryTest]
08:58:12.733 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.j.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodTest].
08:58:12.734 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper from class [org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper]
08:58:12.736 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Found explicit ContextLoader class [org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader] for context configuration attributes [ContextConfigurationAttributes@64bf3bbf declaringClass = 'de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodTest', classes = '{class de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig}', locations = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader']
08:58:12.737 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodTest]
08:58:12.738 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodTest]: using defaults.
08:58:12.743 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
08:58:12.744 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
08:58:12.745 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@544fe44c, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@31610302, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@71318ec4, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@21213b92]
08:58:12.745 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodTest]
08:58:12.745 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodTest]
08:58:12.752 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.j.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests].
08:58:12.753 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper from class [org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper]
08:58:12.762 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Found explicit ContextLoader class [org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader] for context configuration attributes [ContextConfigurationAttributes@3108bc declaringClass = 'de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests', classes = '{class de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig}', locations = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader']
08:58:12.762 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests]
08:58:12.763 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests]: using defaults.
08:58:12.769 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
08:58:12.770 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
08:58:12.770 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@335eadca, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@210366b4, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@eec5a4a, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@2b2948e2]
08:58:12.770 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests]
08:58:12.770 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests]
08:58:12.786 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.787 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.788 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.789 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.790 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.790 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.793 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:12.793 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest]
08:58:13.324 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@6193932a testClass = PeriodRangeTest, testInstance = de.unit4.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest@647fd8ce, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@159f197 testClass = PeriodRangeTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]]].
08:58:13.395 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:58:13.398 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:58:13.398 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
08:58:13.401 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [integrationTest] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [systemEnvironment]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)

2015-07-20 08:58:13.766  INFO 8552 --- [           main] d.u.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest   : Starting PeriodRangeTest on gsender with PID 8552 (C:\Users\gsender\Documents\workspace-libs\FinancialsUtility\target\test-classes started by GSender in C:\Users\gsender\Documents\workspace-libs\FinancialsUtility)
2015-07-20 08:58:13.812  INFO 8552 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@524d6d96: startup date [Mon Jul 20 08:58:13 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-07-20 08:58:15.572  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Creating embedded database 'FanUtilDB'
2015-07-20 08:58:15.823  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql]
2015-07-20 08:58:15.851  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql] in 28 ms.
2015-07-20 08:58:15.851  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [data.sql]
2015-07-20 08:58:15.990  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [data.sql] in 139 ms.
08:58:16.007 [main] INFO  Datasource org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy@60094a13 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig getDataSource 54 
08:58:16.197 [main] INFO  oas_company = 28 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.199 [main] INFO  oas_agm = 2 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.201 [main] INFO  oas_agmlist = 2 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.203 [main] INFO  com_usr = 52 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
08:58:16.205 [main] INFO  com_capab = 17 || de.unit4.financials.JUnitConfig countTableRows 74 
2015-07-20 08:58:16.271  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/gsender/Documents/workspace-libs/FinancialsUtility/target/test-classes/schema.sql]
2015-07-20 08:58:16.285  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/gsender/Documents/workspace-libs/FinancialsUtility/target/test-classes/schema.sql] in 14 ms.
2015-07-20 08:58:16.289  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/gsender/Documents/workspace-libs/FinancialsUtility/target/test-classes/data.sql]
2015-07-20 08:58:16.391  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/gsender/Documents/workspace-libs/FinancialsUtility/target/test-classes/data.sql] in 101 ms.
2015-07-20 08:58:16.555  INFO 8552 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-07-20 08:58:16.590  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2015-07-20 08:58:16.682  INFO 8552 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
2015-07-20 08:58:16.684  INFO 8552 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-07-20 08:58:16.686  INFO 8552 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-07-20 08:58:16.979  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-07-20 08:58:17.136  INFO 8552 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2015-07-20 08:58:17.424  INFO 8552 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-07-20 08:58:18.153  INFO 8552 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2015-07-20 08:58:18.178  INFO 8552 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2015-07-20 08:58:19.063  INFO 8552 --- [           main] d.u.financials.periods.PeriodRangeTest   : Started PeriodRangeTest in 5.659 seconds (JVM running for 7.356)
08:58:19.099 [main] INFO  Datasource org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy@60094a13 || de.unit4.financials.periods.CurrentPeriodDBFactory getCurrentPeriod 63 
08:58:19.127 [main] INFO  oas_company = 0 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.128 [main] INFO  oas_agm = 0 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.128 [main] INFO  oas_agmlist = 0 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.129 [main] INFO  com_usr = 52 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
08:58:19.130 [main] INFO  com_capab = 17 || de.unit4.financials.FinancialsUtilApplicationTests countTableRows 40 
2015-07-20 08:58:19.134  INFO 8552 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@524d6d96: startup date [Mon Jul 20 08:58:13 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-07-20 08:58:19.386  INFO 8552 --- [       Thread-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-07-20 08:58:19.387  INFO 8552 --- [       Thread-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2015-07-20 08:58:19.398  INFO 8552 --- [       Thread-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

For Table creation I use (example):

```
drop table IF EXISTS oas_company;
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS  oas_company  ( 
    code                varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    code_cs             int NOT NULL,
```

For data inserts I use:

```
delete from oas_agm;
INSERT INTO oas_agm(code, tstamp, name, sname, adddate, deldate, moddate, usrname)
  VALUES('U4SW-JUNIT-1', 1, 'Account Test Entwicklung', 'debit', '2015-07-15 00:00:00.0', NULL, '2015-07-15 15:31:39.0', 'INSTALL');
```

Thanks for any help on this confusing result.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution: Hibernate recreates the tables after initialisation (by Spring Boot). I added `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to *application.properties* and the problem was gone.

This is the first time this happened in a project. It is also unclear why only three out of five tables are recreated. At first I assumed it was due to an "old" database file, but then I switched from *H2* to *HSQL* and the problem stayed. An error from Hibernate showed me the path to solution (*unable to delete...*).